# Web design PHP SQL Query issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This is one of my functions in my function.php file. Right now I'm just trying to get it to output 1 or 0 depending if the username is in the MYSQL DB.

```
function retrieve_single($col, $table, $item, $con) {
  require_once('include/global.php');

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = Username1";
  $conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
  if ($conn->connect_error) { 
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '.$conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR ); 
  }
  $rs=$conn->query($sql);

  if($rs === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
  } else {
    $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
    echo $rows_returned;
  }
}
```

I keep changing stuff around trying to figure out what's wrong with it, all I know it is a sql error I keep getting. As of right now I have it written without the variables because of trying to figure out the problem.

The global.php:

```
$DBServer = 'localhost'; $DBUser   = 'root'; $DBPass   = ''; $DBName   = 'social';
```

Can anyone help me out! I know the problem is simple, as this is my first time having this problem

Comment: Very vague title and you haven't told us the error! `Unknown column Username1` by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you say that you're getting and you haven't shown us, is caused by this:

```
WHERE username =  Username1 ";
                 ^         ^ // missing quotes
```

It needs to have single quotes placed around `Username1`

I.e.:

```
WHERE username = 'Username1'";
```

If you're not already doing so, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: Ask the OP lol @JakeGould I'm next to 100% certain that username isn't an `int`. Usernames are usually text. If OP comes back and says "this doesn't work", then we'll know for sure ;-)

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense too Jake. If OP chooses yours, great. We'd of found the source of the problem. @JakeGould

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice the missing quote. That made a big difference. Username1 was a testing username in the database. And sorry I should have been a bit more clear

Answer (score 2):

Your function is very confusing. How are you calling it in the rest of your code?

```
function retrieve_single($col, $table, $item, $con) {
  require_once('include/global.php');

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = Username1";
  $conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
  if ($conn->connect_error) { 
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '.$conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR ); 
  }
  $rs=$conn->query($sql);

  if($rs === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
  } else {
    $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
    echo $rows_returned;
  }
}
```

So your interface to `retrieve_single()` has the following `$col`, `$table`, `$item` and `$con`. But where are they used in the function? They seem 100% not used at all. So you are just calling it like `retrieve_single()` and hope it works? Seems odd.

Then within your function your query is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = Username1";
```

Which makes little sense.  It should at least have single quotes around it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'Username1'";
```

But it seems like it should be a variable like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$Username1'";
```

But that said, where would `$Username1` come from? Perhaps—looking at your interface variables—that should be `$item` like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$item'";
```

Perhaps the whole function needs to be refactored to accommodate all the oddities I noticed like this:

```
function retrieve_single($col, $table, $item, $con) {
  require_once('include/global.php');

  $sql = "SELECT $col FROM $table WHERE username = '$item'";
  if ($con->connect_error) { 
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '.$con->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR ); 
  }
  $rs=$conn->query($sql);

  if($rs === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
  } else {
    $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
    echo $rows_returned;
  }
}
```

Using this refactored function you would access it like this outside of the function:

```
$con = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
retrieve_single('*', 'users', 'Username1', $con);
```

Then again, no idea how you are actually using your function in your larger code so this is me just winging it based on what you have presented. As it stands, the function itself—as you have presented it—is just problematic.

Comment: I know I put in my answer first, however Jake, your answer is better suited for possible scenarios. I did +1 yours.

Comment: Thanks for that Jake. I did think about the possible missing `$` and for a possible variable, before you posted yours and then noticed you had covered that in yours so, no sense for me now to make a note of it if since, well... you covered it and might pass off as if I've copied yours. ;-) cheers